# Spring Integration cheat sheet

Tags: spring, design-patterns, spring-integration

Does anybody knows where I can find a cheat sheet collecting all the components of Spring Integration and a brief description of what any of those do?

Answer (score 2):

Why [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/) isn't enough?
From other side the theory is here: [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/)

Comment: Also, I believe there is a DZone RefCardz in the works. Not sure when they plan on releasing it.

Comment: I was looking for a quick reference that could help me during the integration graph, Reference Manual or EIP Books (I also have Spring Integration in Action) are good but a little bit 'clumsy'.